# Selenium : After clicking a Click in home page , one more screen appears and it got altogether different new DOM loaded

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver

Selenium : After clicking a Click in home page , one more screen appears and it got altogether different new DOM loaded and am currently unable to handle any elements using selenium and getting Element not found exception

Note : Tried Manually to load the same page and in browser console provided the same element and got nothing . but after long time it shows element. Is there a way to handle it?

Answer (score 0):

You can handle your child window using below code. Basically we need to switch web driver control from your parent window to child window and once you finish process then again you have to switch control back to your parent window for further process. We can use window_handles to get handle of all opened windows by web driver and then we can switch from one window to another in a web application

[Different Windows](https://seleniumwithjavapython.wordpress.com/selenium-with-python/switching-between-windows-and-alerts/)

Python :

```
driver.switch_to_window(driver.window_handles[-1])
title=driver.title
```

To handle synchronisation issue you can always use different types of waits available in the selenium e.g: implicit, explicit etc.